# Sublime text: how to turn off the synchronized scrolling of the same views to one file?

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text(My version is Sublime Text 3), there is 'File->New View into File' feature. When I put two views of the same file into different groups respectively, they seem to scroll synchronizingly with the right a little ahead of the left. So I can't compare two portions of the file which are a little far from each other. Can I turn off this 'smart' feature and how? :)

Comment: I just found a trick: File->New Window, open the file in the new window, then drag the tab in the new window to the other group in the old window. Thus the two tabs can scroll separately.

Comment: What OS are you on? Seems that on Linux they are not synchronized and scrolled separately.

Comment: Do you have a plugin like https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll installed?

Comment: You are right! It's the problem. When I disable the BufferScroll plugin, it's OK. And I noticed that someone has posted the problem [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3503). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably happening because of an installed plug-in called BufferScroll. But you don't need to uninstall BufferScroll to fix this. You can just change one of its preferences.

1. From the "Preferences" menu, choose "Package Settings" and then "BufferScroll".
2. Paste `{ "synch_scroll" : false }` into that file. (If that file is not already empty, just add `, "synch_scroll" : false` to the last line in that file. )
3. Save the preferences file and create a new "New View Into File".

Comment: Thanks, confirmed that this worked for me on Sublime Text 3 on a Mac.